# Comparing sequential search to binary search

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, binary-search, asymptotic-complexity, linear-search

Assume I have an unsorted array of real numbers, of length `N`. I want to find the largest nonpositive number `y`, and then the first number `x` smaller than `y` in the array, and the first number `z` bigger than `y`.

I'd like to theoretically compare sequential search to binary search non-asymptotically (i.e. not just with big Os) to find these values. Is it reasonable to state:

- Sequential search requires

  - `0` comparisons for sorting,
  - `3*N` comparisons for searching (three sequential searches).
- Binary search requires

  - `2*N*ln(N) ≈ 1.39*N*log_2(N)` comparisons for sorting ([quicksort, average](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr03/cs226/lectures/analysis.4up.pdf))
    ,
  - up to `log_2(N)` comparisons for searching (only one search, since array is sorted and we can therefore look at neighboring values in the sorted array to find `x` and `z` once we have found `y`).

And therefore, can I state that binary search will be faster if

```
1.39*N*log_2(N) + log_2(N) < 3*N 
<=> 
0 < N < 3.44779
```

i.e. only for extremely small arrays?

Comment: If you want to search a value only one time, the do a sequential search. If it's gonna be more than once, consider sorting the array first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your conclusion is correct. However usually the point of using a sorted array (or any other organized structure) is when you perform the preprocessing step only once or rarely - in contrast to frequent queries. After many queries the preprocessing cost pays off.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not a valid conclusion, for several reasons.

- You're only considering the cost of comparisons (which is minor), rather than the cost of branches and swaps.
- You're using an approximation for the average number of comparisons performed by quicksort which is only asymptotically valid.
- You're using "number of operations" as a stand-in for "speed". Real processors do not take a constant time to execute a given operation, and the total time they spend on a procedure is not the sum of each operation's execution time.

Comment: Short of comparing runtimes (which favors binary search in my implementation for an array of length 100), what (if any) theoretical arguments could I use to justify using one algorithm over another?

Comment: Well, now you know why there's such an emphasis on *asymptotic* analysis, which trumps any constant factor for sufficiently large data. :-) The only way to conclusively show that one algorithm is faster than another for a bounded problem size is to profile it on the target hardware.